# Extreme optimization of a WordPress site for a simple landing page

Tags: wordpress, optimization

WordPress does several operations to show a single page, so the first idea which came to my mind was to save the website as follows:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://localhost/mywebsite
```

Then, upload the saved website to my hosting. e.g.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

The idea was to automatize that procces. However I realized that the cache plugins already do that.

I believe the next most important issue is that most of the loaded Javascript is never used. How to load only the Javascript needed? Everything I have found on the Internet just explains how to code it correctly, but not how to tell WordPress to load only the Javascript needed in theme, plugins, etc.

I think the solution is to download the website as I described. Then use some software or online service to reduce the Javascript and CSS code to the minimum, so only the needed Javascript functions will be on the website. Does that sofware exist? Is there some other procedure a better option?

Answer (score 0):

if you google js minify and css minify there are online tools. e.g. http://jscompress.com/

You are right about the un-needed js and css it seems every plugin and theme loads a js file and css files (boilerplates and bootstrap) which is loaded on every page which is very wasteful (wordpress sites can often load 30-40 js files alone), but i suppose its up to end user to optimize.

you can use `wp_dequeue_script( $handle );` to remove un-needed js and css but you need to find out the handle first so to output the handles:

```
     function inspect_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
        echo $handle . ' | ';
    endforeach;
}


function inspect_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) :
        echo $handle . ' | ';
    endforeach;
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'inspect_styles', 1000 ); //repeat for js
```

now you can dequeue the lot and add 1 optimized js file and css file (the below is for a page template, if you want it in your functions you can qualify its by testing url / wp query vars)

```
     function dequeue_script(){

         wp_dequeue_script( 'contact-form-7' ); 
         wp_dequeue_style( 'contact-form-7' );

         //enqueue new scripts / styles

         wp_enqueue_script( 'homepage-js', 'custom-url', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
         wp_enqueue_style('homepagecss', 'custom-url');
     }
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Obviously to make use of browser caching as much as possible, be clever about your files, a cut down version just for the landing page is a good idea as you want this to load immediately.

**But on the landing page what is the next page/pages?**

Pre-load the css file for these pages to the cache whilst the user is on the page (not during page load)! Any big js files to be loaded and you think the person will spend some time on a page - pre-load the js file!